# Using Index in forEach Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects being displayed in a table... My goal is to access a specific item within the array by clicking on that item in the table.  I would then be able to add/remove classes and access the values, which is ultimately what I need to do.

Here's where I'm stuck...

```
myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
// Sort through array, render to DOM
  document.getElementById('myElementID').innerHTML +=
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' +
    item.thing +
    '</td>' +
    '<td' +
    item.thing2 +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';

// Completely stuck... I've added an event listener to each table row.

  addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    console.log(//I want to log the index of the item I just clicked on);
  });
});
```

Please forgive me if this is very easy or I'm going about this all wrong, but I'm very new to all of this and I haven't been able to structure my question in such a way that google is helpful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - Some html as requested...

```
      <table id="myElementID">
        <tr>
          <th id="heading">Heading1</th>
          <th id="anotherHeading">Heading2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

EDIT again (sorry) ... and a JS fiddle. You'll see that it logs both indexes, instead of just the one I clicked on. https://jsfiddle.net/c4pd5wmg/4/

Comment: do you have any HTML code?

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure because the code above is fragmentary, but provided the `addEventListener` is on the element for `index`, within the handler you can use `index`, since it closes over it and nothing changes it. But please take care when cutting down your code for your question not to remove important parts, like what you're calling `addEventListener` on.

Comment: Hi MapleDanish! Please add some jsfiddle example us, you'll get help easier, if we can see a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing with index etc.. you can attach the event handler to the `tr` and just reference `e.target` in the event handler. I also cleaned up your adding of tr.

```js
const myArray= [{number: 45,otherNumber: 55},{number: 48,otherNumber:58}]

      myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    
          let row = document.createElement("tr");
          let cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.innerHTML = item.number;
          row.appendChild(cell);
          
          cell = document.createElement("td");
          cell.innerHTML = item.otherNumber;
          row.appendChild(cell);
    
          document.getElementById('myElementID').appendChild(row);
        
          row.addEventListener('dblclick', (e) => {
             console.log(e.target);
          });
        });
```

```html
<table id="myElementID">
        <tr>
          <th id="heading">Heading1</th>
          <th id="anotherHeading">Heading2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Hundreds of hours of youtube tutorials and I don't think I've ever seen the ".target" method. All I had to do was add that and everything worked as intended.

Comment: I would for sure add an element to the beginning of the addEventListener also. Otherwise you are looping through constantly adding the event handler to the document level. There are many ways to accomplish things when coding, this just happens to be one that doesn't rely on other variables especially in loops.